# Error inside jquery.validate.js "javaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'call' of undefined or null reference"

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, razor, jquery-validate

I am working on an asp.net mvc-5 web application. and i am using these scripts:-

- jquery 1.10.2
- jquery-ui 1.8.24
- jQuery Validation Plugin 1.11.1

Now when i run the application inside visual studio 2013, the following exception will happen on IE10 , while there will not be any problem on chrome or firefox :-

```
Unhandled exception at line 1234, column 5 in http://localhost:49392/Scripts/jquery.validate.js

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'call' of undefined or null reference
```

the code which will raise the error inside the jquery.validate.js is :-

```
function($) {
    // only implement if not provided by jQuery core (since 1.4)
    // TODO verify if jQuery 1.4's implementation is compatible with older jQuery special-event APIs
    if (!jQuery.event.special.focusin && !jQuery.event.special.focusout && document.addEventListener) {
        $.each({
            focus: 'focusin',
            blur: 'focusout'
        }, function( original, fix ){
            $.event.special[fix] = {
                setup:function() {
                    this.addEventListener( original, handler, true );
                },
                teardown:function() {
                    this.removeEventListener( original, handler, true );
                },
                handler: function(e) {
                    var args = arguments;
                    args[0] = $.event.fix(e);
                    args[0].type = fix;
                    return $.event.handle.apply(this, args);
                }
            };
            function handler(e) {
                e = $.event.fix(e);
                e.type = fix;
                **return $.event.handle.call(this, e);**//this will raise the exception
            }
        });
    }
```

Can anyone adivce how i can solve this problem ?
Thank

Comment: your jquery version please?

Comment: installing jquery migrate may solve this PM> Install-Package jQuery.Migrate

Comment: @PandiyanCool jQuery version is 1.10.2

Comment: i run the Install-Package JQuery.Migrate and it added the following script inside the Scripts folder "jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js" and this solve the issue on IE10 .. thanks. but ca you advice what will the jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js did exactly ?

Comment: I think 1.2.1 version is fine

Comment: For newer jQuery versions (2.1 +) and jQuery Validation(1.13 +) plugin including `additional-methods.min.js` resolves this error.

Answer (score 7):

installing jquery migrate may solve this `PM> Install-Package jQuery.Migrate`

Comment: yes it did ,, but what will this do exactly ? can you adivce ? will it force my web application to use jquery 1.2.1 ?

Comment: if this is the case, then why i can not delete the 1.10.2 and add the new version ?

Comment: it won't force the web app to use 1.2.1, its a fallback support methods and features dropped in current version. If you starting up your project in smaller manner newly, you can go up with the newer version :)

Comment: So what will be the differences between using the migrate scripts and removing my previous jQuery 1.10.2 and add version 1.2.1 ??

Comment: See using migrate 1.2.1 does not means you are using jquery 1.2.1.. Using jquery 1.10 is fine to support IE9+

Comment: so what will migrate 1.2.1 do exactly ? can u adivce ?